# Guaranteed way to call CleanUp logic after all GameObjects destroyed

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have a system that does initialization logic in `Awake()` and has an appropriate `[DefaultExecutionOrder(-100)]` attribute to guarantee its `Awake()` be called before each other "playable" game objects `Awake()`. Now I need the reverse logic, i need to call a function after each game object being destroyed.

I tried to traverse over root objects in main component's `OnDestroy()`, check if there's an object that is still alive (i.e. cast to bool gives `true`), and "pass the baton" of deinitialization to it (adding a CleanUp component on it). Then when this object's `OnDestroy()` is called it does the same logic, checks if there is at least one object alive, etc... The problem is that it doesn't work as i expected.

Also tried to make `OnDestroy()` async and check if there's no alive objects in the scene and wait for 100ms in a loop. The result is that playmode exits but the loop still goes on valid objects outside the playmode

Another approach was to instantiate an object with cleanup component in main component's `OnDestroy()` but Unity does not allow to instantiate in `OnDestroy()` event

Also tried to implement this logic in component's destructor but it was weirdly been called even before the `Awake()`

The other possible approach would be to use `ISubsystem` interface Unity provides but there's no clear documentation on how to use it.

I don't want to use any kind of "global factories" to instantiate and control objects

A possible way to workaround is to use other components' dependent logic in `OnApplicationQuit()` instead of `OnDestroy()` but it is the most fallback solution for me

What is the best way for component to be initialized before each other and outlive everyone?

Comment: What is it you actually need to do? Maybe there's a better method than using `Destroy`. Also, how are the objects you want destroyed created - design or run time?

Comment: "What is it you actually need to do?" >>> I need to tweak some script that is responsible for loading/unloading native libraries. [DllImport] can't unload library after you exit playmode so you can't rebuild the library without reopening the editor each time.    <<< "design or run time"  >>> Both

Comment: Hmm, don't know, sorry. Interesting problem though.

Comment: @IC_ More than year ago I solved the native library problem by rewriting some internal id in the library file after rebuild (this was on Unix, but .dll files should be similar in this way), which forces Unity to reload the plugin. The pro here is that you are essentially writing development code and that functionality should stay out (or separate) of Unity application code.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why don't you want to use global resource management? The .dll is a global resource, too. What you're describing is exactly a *shared pointer*-style resource, where the load happens before returning the first call of `acquire` and the unload happens before returning the first call of `release`. This is the canonical way of dealing with unmanaged resources in managed environments.

Comment: @OneFullTimeEquivalent What do you mean under "global resource management"? My goal is to have an environment where i can edit C++ code, rebuild it without Unity's locks on the library which prevent compiler from writing to busy resource. Rewriting of internal id sounds interesting, how did you achieve this? I guess you made a post-build script that somehow patches binary code of the library so checksums become different and Unity thinks it's another library and loads it again into the memory? So the problem with inability to write to locked file is still not solved that way

Comment: Global resource management >> I mean something like a factory pattern that keeps track of the instances. On unix the file is not "locked" so rewriting is also not a problem. Maybe you need to go with a factory method then and load/unload at runtime.

Comment: @OneFullTimeEquivalent unfortunately I'm on windows and I wanted to make it crossplatform solution so i could work on both linux/windows seamlessly. No, i just don't want make custom factories because it is error-prone. You can simply forget about them and it'll create unwanted complications in future (like networked instatiation handling with an external framework)

Comment: Well, I think your constraints are too narrow then. This is how everyone does it. Wrapping native code into a C# class which unloads the library in its destructor is standard practice and I don't see how it provokes any bugs. The only way something can go wrong is if you somehow still hold a reference to that wrapper object and it cannot be destroyed. But as I understand it, you will use the library exclusively during runtime so the reference is lost no later than the application's termination.